# Recovering Hive Wallet private key with passphrase

Tags: wallet, private-key, passphrase, recover-private-key, hive

Because Hive Wallet shut down and I didn't export the private keys, I have no way to access my Bitcoins. Is there someway, given a passphrase, to find the private key?
Thanks in advance.
P.S I already tried bip32.org. It gave me incorrect addresses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might want to experiment with libbitcoin's command line interface called bitcoin explorer (bx). Instructions for using v3.0 bx commands used below are found [here](https://github.com/libbitcoin/libbitcoin-explorer/wiki) in the right pane.

Assuming there is no mnemonic password, and the associated **`public key is compressed,` the associated BIP 32/39/44 m/44'/0'/0'/0/0 private key and address** can be computed as follows:

1) % echo "artwork crowd need rent install fire draw escape moment myth strong belt chair quiz cinnamon lab park leopard bicycle empty harvest cream matter teach" | bx mnemonic-to-seed | bx hd-new -v 76066276 | bx hd-private -d -i 44 | bx hd-private -d -i 0 | bx hd-private -d -i 0 | bx hd-private -i 0 | bx hd-private -i 0 | bx hd-to-ec | sed 's/$/01/' | bx base58check-encode -v 128

`L58MiHSepQEyenRzb8EENW3mXv1DYExG5XMGCgdoZC94yqi5eBRd`

2) % echo "artwork crowd need rent install fire draw escape moment myth strong belt chair quiz cinnamon lab park leopard bicycle empty harvest cream matter teach" | bx mnemonic-to-seed | bx hd-new -v 76066276 | bx hd-private -d -i 44 | bx hd-private -d -i 0 | bx hd-public -d -i 0 | bx hd-public -i 0 | bx hd-public -i 0 | bx hd-to-ec | bx ec-to-address -v 0

`19JdNez3RdtfYXCnH1NohFxY5sRWRu6xbW`

Assuming there is no mnemonic password, and the associated **`public key is uncompressed,` the associated m/44'/0'/0'/0/0 BIP 32/39/44 private key and address** can be computed as follows:

3) % echo "artwork crowd need rent install fire draw escape moment myth strong belt chair quiz cinnamon lab park leopard bicycle empty harvest cream matter teach" | bx mnemonic-to-seed | bx hd-new -v 76066276 | bx hd-private -d -i 44 | bx hd-private -d -i 0 | bx hd-private -d -i 0 | bx hd-private -i 0 | bx hd-private -i 0 | bx hd-to-ec | bx base58check-encode -v 128

`5KcCVPJbPyUBa2geWwCcCfkg6C6wVq2C7v6VpWNUmT5zzkdph14`

4) % echo "artwork crowd need rent install fire draw escape moment myth strong belt chair quiz cinnamon lab park leopard bicycle empty harvest cream matter teach" | bx mnemonic-to-seed | bx hd-new -v 76066276 | bx hd-private -d -i 44 | bx hd-private -d -i 0 | bx hd-private -d -i 0 | bx hd-private -i 0 | bx hd-private -i 0 | bx hd-to-ec | bx ec-to-public -u | bx ec-to-address -v 0

`1MGahZGaVNM5Y26A58sa5LajiyeopnBez6`

Answer (score 0):

When you say passphrase, are you talking about the 12 word seed phrase, or do you have a password protected encrypted wallet? If you still have the wallet backup (bitcoinkit.wallet) and have a password (not seed word list) that encrypted the private key(s), you can export your private key(s) with a command line tool I made. I ran into this same issue, and it worked for me. Have a look at https://github.com/JesseCorrington/bitcoinj-wallet-export